# How to select checkbox in AngularJS to select only unique matching items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to select common items from the table using Angular check-box.

This is my mock UI-Table:

```
  Order Id  | Delivery Mode  | Select
      1     | Speed          | ::checkbox::
      2     | Normal         | ::checkbox::
      3     | Contractor     | ::checkbox:: 
      4     | Contractor     | ::checkbox::
      5     | Normal         | ::checkbox::
      6     | Speed          | ::checkbox::
      7     | Speed          | ::checkbox::
                       :::Create Order button:::
```

Conditions:

- All checkboxes are enabled on page-load. I should only be able to
  select orders of same delivery mode.
- Whenever I select mixed delivery    mode, I should display error
  message(lets say alert).

This is the orders list I have used to populate the table:

```
var orders = [
{
  orderId: 1,
  deliveryMode: 'Speed'
},
{
  orderId: 2,
  deliveryMode: 'Normal'
},
...
...
];
```

Controller:

```
$scope.createOrder = function(order) {
 if(order.selected){
  // Whenever the order is selected I push to array
  $scope.collectOrders.push(order.deliveryMode);
 }else{
  // And when any deselect happens *(using lodash)
  _.remove($scope.collectOrders, function(order){
    return order === order.deliveryMode;
  });
 }

  if (_.uniq($scope.collectOrders).length > 1){
    alert('Mixed Delivery mode selected');
  }

};
```

However this logic is not correct.
Can you help with an efficient solution to solve this problem.
I should only be able to select common delivery mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet for selecting similar type of deliveryMode.

HTML Code :

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in orders track by $index">
    <td name="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.checked" ng-style="row.checkboxStyle" ng-click="setSelectedRow(row)" /></td>
</tr>
```

JS Code :

```
$scope.mySelections = [];
$scope.setSelectedRow = function(row) {
    if ($scope.mySelections.length === 0) {
        $scope.mySelections.unshift(row);
        return;
    }
    var index = $scope.mySelections.indexOf(row);
    if (row.checked) {
        if ($scope.mySelections.length > 0) {
            if (row.deliveryMode === $scope.mySelections[index - 1].deliveryMode) {
                $scope.mySelections.unshift(row);
            } else {
                alert("Mixed Mode Selected");
            }

        } else {
            $scope.mySelections.unshift(row);
        }


    } else {
        $scope.mySelections.splice($scope.mySelections.indexOf(row), 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: I am using Angular Datatable to display the UI-Table with AJAX mode. http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withAjax So I guess I will not be able to use your solution with track by $index on table row.

Comment: @FakirTrappedInCode you can delete the html part track by $index but can use any function that can pass the value back to controller as done above.

Comment: where should the alert be placed?

Comment: code edited and alert placed where mixed mode is selected.

Comment: var index = $scope.mySelections.indexOf(row); always returns -1 and as a result $scope.mySelections[index - 1].deliveryMode ends in Exception

Comment: Am I missing push to $scope.mySelections?

Comment: @FakirTrappedInCode I have added the validation for that error.

Comment: Doesnt make sense.. it is always returning because  $scope.mySelections.length > 0 is always true after every selection

Comment: If you think your solution works can you jsbin/jsfiddle? Thanks.

Comment: @FakirTrappedInCode I have updated the answer and will soon update you the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score -1):

You could use ng-disable on your checkbox whenever a type selected isn't the same one as the type of the current checkbox.

```
<md-checkbox ng-repeat="order in orders" ng-disabled="collectOrders[0].deliveryMode !== order.deliveryMode" ng-change= "createOrder(order)">
```

Comment: User would need some feedback as to why we could not select a checkbox.

Comment: Disables checkbox upfront.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. But without context it's pretty hard to consider UX problems. It would make no sense to me as a user to be able to pass some "order" and then get a pop up to tell me i can't select multiple types. I'd rather have it disabled with a small tooltip on them to explain it to me.